# Hide fields in Lotus iNotes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I need to hide/disable certain fields in iNotes address book (Internet's directory). When authenticated users try to browse other user's details from address book (`New Message` --> `TO` --> `Select addresses` --> `Details`) I want to hide/disable `Details` button. Browser page source inspection of that button led me to `iNotes/Forms9.nsf` database but when I opened Forms9.nsf in Designer didn't find any form or view that associates with any button/field in address book. Also tried in Designer to hide/disable certain fields which relate to people document in names.nsf (`$PersonInheritableSchema`) but without success.  Is there any way to hide these fields/buttons?

Answer (score 2):

Customizing iNotes is quite complicated. There are no classical design elements to be manipulated: you need to create a new "forms9_x.nsf" database and manipulate the javascript source code there... unfortunately it is highly obfuscated and minified so that every change is quite painful.

There once have been presentations about how to do it, but by searching for "inotes customization" I could only find one that is not completely valid anymore as the structure in forms changed significantly since then. You could start with your research on this [HCL help page](https://help.hcltechsw.com/domino/10.0.1/conf_customizingthelookoflotusinotes_t.html), but I promise it will be a long and painful way to go.

Comment: OK. What about disabling/hiding fields in Person Documents? I've found in names.nsf form '($PersonInheritableSchema)' that has all person document fields but no matter I check hide button in properties of certain fields nothing happens. All fields all still visible. Is there any way to remove/hide certain fields in Person Documents from Designer?

Comment: Again: the code for these elements is NOT in forms and views… it cannot be hidden using classic Notes development…

Comment: By this do you mean code for the elements in iNotes or generally all code for fields in Internet Directory person documents (names.nsf)?

Comment: I mean: everything that is shown directly in iNotes interface….

Comment: OK. I got it - everything about iNotes interface, but what about fields in Person Document of Domino users that are accesible apart from iNotes? For example some fields about mail system, domain. work/home etc that are accesible from Domino Administator or Notes client.

Comment: then you did something wrong: for names.nsf the subform you found is the right place for this... BUT: Never edit directly in names.nsf... Create a custom template and do it there... otherwise your work might be lost every morning (depending on your environment and enabled design task)...

Comment: Hello, I need to customize iNotes by just adding a custom button. To do this, I need to know where put my script in the "HCL iNotes Common Form" database (iNotes/form9.nsf). In previous domino version, there was in subform Custom_Js_lite where I can write a Custom_Scene_Actions_Lite function to add a new button but IBM or Hcl has changed this. All code in subform in this database is now different ... Somebody have some information to give me that can help me ?